# GLUT_SINGLE displays a black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

It took me >1 day and I still haven't figured out why. 
I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, trying to make a simple OpenGL to work in c++.

whenever I used GLUT_SINGLE parameter, it gives me a full black screen. I had to click mouse randomly on that screen in order to get out. This is so much annoying. Possibly a bug. Can anybody help?

Here is the code that I use, drawing a simple triangle in c++:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void myReshape(int a, int b)
{
}

void myMouse(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
}

void myKeyboard(unsigned char c, int a, int b)
{
}

void myInit()
{
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv); // initiaize the toolkit
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); // set the display mode 
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480); // set window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); 
    glutCreateWindow("first window");

    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);


    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    //glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    //glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);

    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be no need to call `glSwapBuffers()` on a single-buffered window. It should not have an effect, though.

Comment: Works fine for me on Win7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Ubuntu 9.10, with the latest updates. When compiling your code with

```
g++ -o test -lglut -lGLU -lGL test.cpp
```

it works perfectly. This could indeed be a bug.

Do other OpenGL applications work with single buffering? Did you try a different video driver (non-free vs. free)?

Comment: yes, i also think the problem is with my graphic card driver. I'm still trying to look for a good graphic card driver for my laptop. It is Radeon Xpress 200M on Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. Ubuntu 9.10, x64

> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Q35 GEM 20090712 2009Q2 RC3
>
> OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.6

I suspect your driver may be buggy.  Try disabling desktop Visual Effects (System -> Preferences -> Appearance).