# using glBitmap not rendering anything on screen

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying out a simple implementation of trying to render a bitmap font, as given in the Red book. The problem is that my viewport is blank throughout and nothing comes on the screen.

Here's the code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

GLubyte A[14] = {
    0xc0,0x00,
    0x60,0xc0,
    0x3f,0x80,
    0x11,0x00,
    0x0a,0x00,
    0x0a,0x00,
    0x04,0x00,
};

void init(void)
{
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
}

void display(void)
{
    float c[4]; 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, c);
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]);
    printf("%x\n",A[0]);

    glRasterPos2f(20,20);
    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION_VALID, c);
    printf("%f\n", c[0]);

    glBitmap(12,7,0,0,11,0,A);
    //glBitmap(12,7,0,0,11,0,A);
    //glBitmap(12,7,0,0,11,0,A);

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, c);
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]);
    glFlush();  
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,w,0, h, -1.0, 1.0);
    //gluOrtho2D(0,1,0,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("FOnt");
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have added that. Using GLUT on Ubuntu 10.04, gcc, ATI Radeon HD 3670. Still having problems running it though

Comment: Which driver?  `radeon` classic, gallium, or `fglrx`?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, didnt have access to the internet for some time. I think radeon classic, it just says radeon when I run sudo lshw -C video

Comment: Ah, sorry, meant which X driver.  Try `glxinfo | grep renderer`.

Comment: Maybe this one too: `glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL (vendor|renderer|version|shading)"`

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) on Vista64 (compiled as 32-bit), Radeon HD 6570.  VS 2008.

**EDIT:** On Linux too:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Ubuntu 10.04 amd64, Intel HD Graphics 3000, `Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT`

**EDIT2:**

Try using double-buffering via `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB)` or `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)` and adding `glutSwapBuffers()` to the end of your `display()` function.

And/or try disabling your [compositor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager#Linux) (`compiz`, `kwin`, `unity`, `GNOME Shell`, etc) if you have one enabled.

[Might be a driver bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209956/glut-single-displays-a-black-screen)

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace `GL_SINGLE` with `GLUT_DOUBLE`
2. Replace `glFlush()` with `glutSwapBuffers()`
3. Add `glLoadIdentity()` after `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`

Then it should work